# JQAssistant: ScanIncludes and Relationship to containing Directory/Project

Tags: jqassistant

I'd like to scan additional directories (for profile-Files):

```
<scanInclude>
    <path>
        ${project.basedir}/src/main/profiles
    </path>
</scanInclude>
```

which is working, as visible in the Debug-Output

```
[INFO] Entering C:/..common/common-api/src/main/profiles
[DEBUG] Scanning /weld.profile
```

Found files are visible in Neo4J as expected:

```
match (f:File) where f.fileName ends with ".profile" return f;
```

returns the files.

However, there's no :CONTAINS Relationship to the Directory/Project the Files are contained in (contrary to, for example a beans.xml File).

There is a :CONTAINS Relationship, but only to a File-Node of the absolute Path of the File, which is not marked as Directory, Artifact or Container.

Is there a way to create this Relationship via Configuration?
Perhaps via

```
<scope>
 ...
</scope>
```

?

I'm not aware of the correct/possible values for `<scope>` however...

Regards,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scanInclude should generate a `Directory` labeled node representing `${project.basedir}/src/main/profiles` which is referenced by a `CONTAINS` relation from the node representing the Maven Project.

The directory itself should provide `CONTAINS` relations to all files in it (e.g. `weld.profile`).

As a Cypher pattern the structure should look like this:

```
(project:Maven:Project)-[:CONTAINS]->(profiles:Directory{name:"profiles"}),
(profiles)-[:CONTAINS]->(profile:File{name:"weld.profile"})
```

Can you verify this?

The scope parameter gives plugins a hint about the content, e.g. if a directory is the output folder of the Java compiler the scope "java:classpath" will activate the bytecode scanner.

Comment: Thanks, somehow I missed the CONTAINS relation from the Maven Project Node, now it looks as expected.